How to solve this npm install problem in laravel app?
npm ERR! Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Windows\install.js'
npm ERR!     at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1144:15)
npm ERR!     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:27)
npm ERR!     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12)
npm ERR!     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
npm ERR!   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
npm ERR!   requireStack: []

I've tried npm install in laravel app
